# Scheme - difference between if and or

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

does somebody know what the difference between if and or in Scheme is or why I can't use if to replace or as an identifier? I posted some code below.
Thank's!

```
;if definition
(define heiner-or
   (lambda (test-1 test-2)
    (if test-1 
      #t
      test-2)))

;or definition
> (heiner-or (= 10 10) (> 2 5))
#t
> (heiner-or (> 23 42) (< 5 2))
#f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [`if`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._if%29%29) and [`or`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._or%29%29). `if` is used for testing a condition and executing *only* one of two possible values - if the condition is `true` the first part will get executed, if it's `false` the second part will get executed:

```
(if (= 1 0)
    "not executed"
    "executed")
=> "executed"
```

`or` is a [logical connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) that can receive multiple arguments, it'll return the first non-false value it finds, or `false` if all values are false. Typically you'd use `or` to connect boolean expressions, but that's not always the case:

```
(or #f 7 10)
=> 7

(or (= 1 0) (= 1 2))
=> #f
```

Also bear in mind that in Scheme all values are considered `true`, except `#f`, which is `false`. Regarding the last part of your question: yes, you can use `if` to simulate an `or`, it would be something like this:

```
; equivalent to (or value1 value2)
(if value1
    value1
    value2)
```

The above is a simplification, because ideally we should evaluate `value1` exactly once, and also because this version doesn't support multiple arguments. But beware: the moment you try to write it as a procedure you'll run into trouble!

```
(define (my-or value1 value2)
  (if value1
      value1
      value2))
```

That will *not* work as an `or`, the procedure evaluates *both arguments* before evaluating the `if`, whereas a real `or` only evaluates the needed expressions until it finds a `true` value - that's what we call short-circuit evaluation. To see what I mean, try this:

```
(or 42 (/ 1 0))
=> 42
(my-or 42 (/ 1 0))
=>  /: division by zero
```

We can't truly implement `or`, `if` as procedures, they're *special forms* and need to be implemented at the interpreter level, with special evaluation rules.